# Register single mouse click (C++)

Tags: c++, if-statement, click, mouse

I have two if statements that both respond to my computer mouse.

```
if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LBUTTON))
{
    //Do something
}

//More code in between

if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LBUTTON))
{
    //Do something else
}
```

However, when I click the left mouse button once it is registered for both if statements. "GetAsyncKeyState" seems to return true as long as the mouse button is down (which it inevitably will be for the second if statement), so what should I use instead so that I need to actively click the mouse button a second time in order for the second statement to take effect?

Comment: Normally you'd handle an OnClick event.  What environment/libraries are you using?

Comment: Why do you use Async functions? You can also do this via windows messaging (`PeekMessage` etc.).